# Store float value in uint32_t pointer

Tags: c, msp430

I want to store some float data in the FRAM register of my TI MSP430 microcontroller and have some prolems.

I don't know how I can do this.

With normal integer variables it is no problem.

**Normal integer variables:**

```
void main()
{
    uint32_t value = 25;
    uint32_t framPtr = 0xD000;

    FRAMC_write_uint32_t(value, (uint32_t*)framPtr);
}

void FRAMC_write_uint32_t(uint32_t value,
                          uint32_t *framPtr)
{
    *framPtr = value;
}
```

But with float values it doesn't work. I tried to change the value inside the function to float, but no result.

**This is my float data:**

```
    float value = 1.25;
    uint32_t framPtr = 0xD000;
```

**With this function it doesn't work:**

```
void FRAM_write_float(float value,
                      uint32_t *framPtr)
{
    *framPtr++ = (float)value;
}
```

It saved the data *1.40129846e-45 (DEN) (HEX: 0x00000001)* in my memory bank.

I hope somebody can help me with my problem.
**Thanks!**

Comment: Casting a float to an integer doesn't reinterpret the bits, if that is what you are after. It does value conversion.

Comment: I'm guessing. Because you didn't show how you attempt to actually convert the float. Why you are showing code that *works* instead of code that doesn't is beyond me.

Comment: What is the difference? I don't understand the problem...
When I look into the memory bank, I see the saved value is 1.40129846e-45 (DEN) (HEX: 0x00000001)

Comment: The difference is that `0x00000001` may be an integer representation of `1`, but for floats `0x3F800000` would be `1.0`. Converting values as opposed to reinterpreting bits will have drastically different results.

Comment: Ah, now I understand the problem. But I didn't know how I solve the problem. How can I say my program to shift my float data without converting it to an integer?

Comment: Are you programming in C or C++? The best answer depends on it (and one is not a subset of the other).

Comment: I am programming my microcontroller only in C. I thought there are many comparrison. Should I delete the C++ tag?

Comment: They are quite different. Type punning, which is what I suggested, is not officially allowed in C++, but is allowed in C99 and beyond (with some warnings to the programmer).

Comment: Your code invokes undefined behaviour. Any reason you don't serialise the data to an `uint8_t` array? And on MSP430 you should not use floating point anyway. It has no FPU and calculations easily take >100 times longer than with integers. Most algorithms for such MCUs can be rewritten quite easily with integers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simplest approach to reinterpret the bits would be to use `memcpy`, if you know that `sizeof(float) == sizeof(uint32_t)` <sup>1</sup>

```
float f = /* some_val */;
uint32_t fbits = 0;
memcpy(&fbits, &f, sizeof fbits);
```

Should be safe enough, since unsigned integers don't usually have trap values.

If your compiler supports C99 and onward. You can also do type punning via a union.

```
union {
  float    from;
  uint32_t to;
} pun = { .from = /*some val*/ };

// use pun.to
```

The above doesn't actually copy anything, so may be marginally faster in a tight loop. (And as **[Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4774918/olaf)** points out, this is **the** standard compliant way for modern C).

---

<sup>1</sup>: If your compiler supports it, you should probably [`_Static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Static_assert) on it.

Comment: @StorryTeller It works! I used the above one to solve the problem.
**Thank you!!**

Comment: @Olaf - Isn't memcpy/memove the only way to change the effective type of an object in pre C99? I'm asking, because that's what I've usually seen done.

Comment: @StoryTeller: See the C info-page, we are talking about **standard** C, which is C11. And that is clear about that. See 6.5p6 and the explicit remark about type-punning via `union`. Things were different if OP used a `uint8_t` (which must be the same as `unsigned char`). Anyway, I'd take a different approach and not use floating point at all on the MSP430 (the problem applies to other types like `int64_t` as well, of course).

Comment: @Olaf - Okay so [§6.5 ¶6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p6) prevents me from changing the effective type of `f` here. And I see that according to [§6.2.6.1 ¶4-5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.6.1p4) I'm advising the OP something risking UB. But I must say that I fail to see how type punning of a value may technically work, while memcpy will fail horribly. Any way, thank you for pointing those things out!

Comment: @StoryTeller: You'd be surprised what a modern, highly optimising compiler exploits. That's one reason gcc has (had) a bad rep with embedded programmers (Personally, I like it!). They just assumed some behaviour like assembly did. Note that most of them were not CS experts, but hardware-engineers who learn programming, but not necessarily how a compiler works and the nasty language details. Which is also the reason quite some refused HLLs like C much longer than reasonable. And those are also the rason for commercial compilers being much more conservative using optimistations.